# Bash: Shell String match for ONE, ANOTHER, or BOTH

Tags: string, bash

I have a `$STATUS`.

This is fine:

```
if [ "$STATUS" != "Ok" ]; then blah..
```

This also works:

```
if [ "$STATUS" != "Ok" ] || [ "$STATUS" != "Non-Critical" ]; then blah..
```

Problem I have is matching (or not) when both my strings are in the output.
`$status` can explicitly equal one of 3 things:

- `Ok`
- `Non-Critical`
- Both

When `$status` outputs both, it's displayed on 2 lines e.g:

```
Non-Critical  
Ok
```

Or the reverse:

```
Ok  
Non-Critical
```

How could I match explicitly on one of those 2 above scenarios allow me to act upon it if the match contain something other than that. Any thoughts?

Here is what the output can be and how I want it to behave:
Note, these are explicit matches, not just containing the string.

```
Ok
```

```
Non-Critical
```

```
Ok  
Non-Critical
```

```
Non-Critical  
Ok
```

Anything else is bad. An example of bad is:

```
Ok  
Failure
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to tag it with the language you're trying to solve this in?

Comment: Is this a Bash script? Or some other language? I'm not sure myself, but I imagine the answers will depend on the exact context here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the following are acceptable:

`OK`
`Non-Critical`
`OK\nNon-Critical` (where `\n` is a line break)
`Non-Critical\nOK`

And anything else is not acceptable.

In which case a possibility is (similar to yours above but with the extra cases):

```
if [[ $STATUS == "OK" || $STATUS == "Non-Critical" || $STATUS == $'OK\nNon-Critical' || $STATUS == $'Non-Critical\nOK' ]]; then
  echo "Everything good"
fi
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. I'm not getting it to work for me.
Only 3 scenarios when it's 'good'.
"Ok" on it's own is good. "Non-Critical" it's own is good. Both together are good. 
Both together is the problem I'm having.
Should either "Ok" or Non-Critical" appear along with ANYTHING else, then it's bad. For example:
"Ok
Failure"
I'd flag this is bad.
I hope that makes sense.
(I appreciate it may seem odd having OK and failure together, but my script is reporting on multiple things, but should have lots of Ok's then I only have it display one of each)

Comment: Have updated my answer which I think caters for the 4 scenarios you are trying to match... feels like there should be a more elegant way.

Comment: Does that `\s` work properly in the regex version? It seems to match a literal `s` there, e.g. `[[ xsssy =~ x\s*y ]] && echo y` prints `y`. Seems to work (on Linux with glibc) though if we put the regex in a variable instead. But still, it's a Perl-ism, and probably not supported everywhere. Also note that `=~` searches for a match within the string, i.e. `[[ "foo OK" =~ OK ]] && echo y` prints `y`; you'd need to anchor the start and end of the regex with `^` and `$` to match against the whole string

Comment: Have removed the regex part since its potentially environment specific, needed anchoring to disclude other matches (missed this) and the first suggestion should really do the trick